# Strange Issue with Python Pillow and JPEG files - pixel tuple elements keeps decrementing. Why?

Tags: python, debugging, tuples, python-imaging-library, steganography

I have a (very) rough draft of a steganography python program that encodes a secret message in a picture. For now, I am simply making the 3rd element of each 3000th pixel one higher or one lower depending on the next binary element of the message (message converted to ascii hex and then binary).

My issue is somewhat tangential, but I am including all of my code so if someone really feels like being nice, they can simply copy and past the code (maybe having to pip install pillow, grab the image, and make a separate python script for the myascii module, but that's all).

MY ISSUE: Every time I run this code, print(px[width-1,height-1]) and print(px[width-2,height-2]) decrement by one in each rgb value. I CAN'T FIGURE OUT WHY TO SAVE MY LIFE. So some terminal output is like the following:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> & C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Python_stuff/assorted/steganography/steganography.py
['4B', '65', '6C', '6C', '65', '79', '27', '73', '20', '66', '61', '76', '6F', '72', '69', '74', '65', '20', '63', '6F', '6C', '6F', '72', '20', '69', '73', '20', '67', '72', '65', '65', '6E', '2E']
010010110110010101101100011011000110010101111001001001110111001100100000011001100110000101110110011011110111001001101001011101000110010100100000011000110110111101101100011011110111001000100000011010010111001100100000011001110111001001100101011001010110111000101110
(75, 51, 17)
(74, 50, 16)
(73, 37, 13)
PS C:\Users\xxx> & C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Python_stuff/assorted/steganography/steganography.py
['4B', '65', '6C', '6C', '65', '79', '27', '73', '20', '66', '61', '76', '6F', '72', '69', '74', '65', '20', '63', '6F', '6C', '6F', '72', '20', '69', '73', '20', '67', '72', '65', '65', '6E', '2E']
010010110110010101101100011011000110010101111001001001110111001100100000011001100110000101110110011011110111001001101001011101000110010100100000011000110110111101101100011011110111001000100000011010010111001100100000011001110111001001100101011001010110111000101110
(74, 50, 16)
(73, 49, 15)
(73, 37, 13)
PS C:\Users\xxx> & C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Python_stuff/assorted/steganography/steganography.py
['4B', '65', '6C', '6C', '65', '79', '27', '73', '20', '66', '61', '76', '6F', '72', '69', '74', '65', '20', '63', '6F', '6C', '6F', '72', '20', '69', '73', '20', '67', '72', '65', '65', '6E', '2E']
010010110110010101101100011011000110010101111001001001110111001100100000011001100110000101110110011011110111001001101001011101000110010100100000011000110110111101101100011011110111001000100000011010010111001100100000011001110111001001100101011001010110111000101110
(73, 49, 15)
(72, 48, 14)
(73, 37, 13)
```

The program and module are below:

```
#def encode(myimage):


#def decode(myimage):

import bin_hex_ascii_converter as myascii

myascii.hex_to_dec("34")
#letter_to_ascii_hex(letter):
#hex_to_bin(foo):
from PIL import Image
foo = Image.open("C:/Users/xxx/Pictures/Saved Pictures/funny_image_encoded.jpg")
#foo = Image.open("C:/Users/xxx/Pictures/Saved Pictures/funny_image.jpg")
#myImage.show()

secret_message = "Jimmie's favorite color is green."

msg = []
for let in secret_message:
   msg.append(myascii.letter_to_ascii_hex(let))
print(msg)

msg_bin = ""
for myhex in msg:
   msg_bin += myascii.hex_to_bin(myhex)
print(msg_bin)

px = foo.load()

width = foo.size[0]
height = foo.size[1]

print(px[width-1,height-1])
print(px[width-2,height-2])

secret_separation = 3000
bar = 0
myiter = 0
limit = len(msg_bin)
for i in range(0,height):
   for j in range(0,width):
       if bar % 3000 == 0 and myiter < limit:
           temp = int(msg_bin[myiter])
           if temp == 0:
               temp = -1
           px[j,i] = (px[j,i][0], px[j,i][1], px[j,i][2]+temp)
           myiter += 1
       bar += 1

#px[5,5] = (px[5,5][0], px[5,5][1], px[5,5][2]+1)
foo.save("C:/Users/xxx/Pictures/Saved Pictures/funny_image_encoded.jpg","JPEG")
print(px[5,5])
```

Also, the module I am importing as myascii is:

```
#hex to dec conversion
def hex_to_dec(foo):
    letts = " ABCDEF"
    if foo[0] in letts:
        num1 = 9 + letts.index(foo[0])
    else:
        num1 = int(foo[0])
    if foo[1] in letts:
        num0 = 9 + letts.index(foo[1])
    else:
        num0 = int(foo[1])
    return num1*16 + num0

def ascii_to_letter(foo):
    low_lett = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    upp_lett = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    #ADD comma and period as well
    if foo == 44:
        return ","
    if foo == 46:
        return "."
    if foo == 32:
        return " "
    if foo == 63:
        return "?"
    if foo > 96 and foo < 123:
        return low_lett[foo - 97]
    if foo > 64 and foo < 91:
        return upp_lett[foo - 65]
    #otherwise
    return "*"

def letter_to_ascii_hex(letter):
    return hex(ord(letter))[2:].upper()

# Returning one byte (8 bits)
def hex_to_bin(foo):
    myarr = ["0000",
    "0001",
    "0010",
    "0011",
    "0100",
    "0101",
    "0110",
    "0111",
    "1000",
    "1001",
    "1010",
    "1011",
    "1100",
    "1101",
    "1110",
    "1111"]

    num2 = foo[0]
    if num2 == "A":
        num2 = "1010"
    elif num2 == "B":
        num2 = "1011"
    elif num2 == "C":
        num2 = "1100"
    elif num2 == "D":
        num2 = "1101"
    elif num2 == "E":
        num2 = "1110"
    elif num2 == "F":
        num2 = "1111"
    else:
        num2 = myarr[int(num2)]

    num1 = foo[1]
    if num1 == "A":
        num1 = "1010"
    elif num1 == "B":
        num1 = "1011"
    elif num1 == "C":
        num1 = "1100"
    elif num1 == "D":
        num1 = "1101"
    elif num1 == "E":
        num1 = "1110"
    elif num1 == "F":
        num1 = "1111"
    else:
        num1 = myarr[int(num1)]

    return num2 + num1
```

Also, the picture I am using is here:
https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=FOFci7yV&id=AA468BC3FE90B8D67D34C7884C3578A69D815E52&thid=OIP.FOFci7yV8pJTXQxPI9OYpgHaHk&mediaurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.laughtard.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F02%2F50-Funny-Animal-Pictures-That-You-Need-In-Your-Life-37.jpg&exph=1000&expw=979&q=funny+images&simid=608028465397174105&ck=A56AB62FC7B4F29A99A099EF131B8CDB&selectedindex=0&ajaxhist=0&first=1&scenario=ImageBasicHover&vt=0&sim=11

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but a JPEG image is lossy and won't deliver back the exact same pixel values it was saved with.

Comment: Oh ok. That is still good to know and seems like a possibility. I will try PNG instead, maybe that will correct the issue.

Comment: That was definitely the issue. Thank you, I didn't realize jpegs were lossy.

Answer (score 3):

As Mark Ransom indicated- jpegs are lossy file formats. Changing to png solved the issue.